# Best approach: Having a form in angular containing a list of components which have more forms

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

So I am currently facing following problem:

I have a customer.component which contains a FormsGroup (data like firstname, surname is stored here) and the save-button. A customer can have multiple accounts. I was thinking of creating a new component "account-list.component" for managing all the adding/removing items and stuff. After that I'd create another component called "account-item.component" which has a FormGroup itself (accountNumber and accountName). This component is used in an *ngFor in the account-list.component

But I think if I have this, I would have trouble synchronizing all the forms since the save-button should be disalbed if there are any validation errors in one of the child component's forms. I am also not sure how to implement change detection currently: I imagine, there would be a problem with focusing if I emit data changes from a child component and overriding the changes in the parents component which would be most likeley also the Input for the child component (this would cause the child component to rerender and the focus is lost).

Do you have idea how to approach this problem? I have been thinking about this for the whole day and searching the web, but all I have found was a parent-FormGroup with **one** component having another formGroup. Couldn't find any examples when you have a whole list with formGroups in another formGroup.

I am looking forward for answers and suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I think if I have this, I would have trouble synchronizing all the
>   forms since the save-button should be disalbed if there are any
>   validation errors in one of the child component's forms. I am also not
>   sure how to implement change detection currently: I imagine, there
>   would be a problem with focusing if I emit data changes from a child
>   component and overriding the changes in the parents component which
>   would be most likeley also the Input for the child component (this
>   would cause the child component to rerender and the focus is lost).

Don't overthink things.

[I reproduced form on stackblitz based on you said](https://stackblitz.com/edit/customer-form-with-multiple-accounts)

I used `FormBuilder` to create customer form and `FormArray` for list of accounts.